# What does (not-set) means in FIrebase attribution?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Hi I see (not set) attribution in Firebase Analytic's attribution option along with (Direct) and rest of my attributions...What does it mean? when it gets trigger?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as in AdWords.

*If (not set) appears in your AdWords reports, it means that the website or app you're tracking in the Analytics account is receiving traffic from an AdWords account that is not linked to the reporting view.*

To know more, take a look [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en).

Comment: can this be solved? Means not set should not appear